# Прочитать отдельные биты из массива байтов

Tags: java, byte, bit

Есть массив байт (byte[] data), нужно записать его в JSON и потом прочитать из JSON.
Предполагал сделать это побитово, распознав в каждом байте 1 и 0 и записав их в строку, а между отдельными байтами вставив разделитель в виде маловероятной последовательности символов. Строки всех байтов последовательно конкатенировать и записать в JSON. Но возникает вопрос, как максимально просто прочитать отдельные биты из байта (без использования сторонних библиотек)?

Comment: `сделать это побитово, распознав в каждом байте 1 и 0 и записав их в строку` - не хотите объяснить, зачем это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается довольно просто. Например, так:

```
byte[] data = {127,126,125};

for (byte datum : data) {
    String bitsString = Integer.toBinaryString((int)datum);            
    System.out.println(bitsString); //Напечатайте, или сделайте с битами что-то ещё
}
```

Это (возможно) не окончательное решение, так как у битов не будет ведущих нулей. То есть, если вам нужно представить число 2 в виде строки так: "0010", то два первых нуля придётся добавить вручную, так как данный способ превратит число 2 в строку "10". Но из вопроса непонятно, нужно это или нет.

Общая логика решения такова. У класса Integer есть статический метод toBinaryString. Этот метод возвращает строку битов, переданного целого числа типа int. Поскольку у нас массив byte, а не int, нам нужно делать привидение типов, что и происходит. С полученной строкой делаем, что хотим.

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: Пожалуйста. Удачного обучения!

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, как видится мне во всяком случае, это использование комбинации простых побитовых операций.
Конкретно, небольшой алгоритм a & (~a ^ (1 << (bitIndex - 1))), где **a** - байт в котором происходит проверка. Если полученный байт равен 0 - бит был нулевой, если отличное от 0 - бит был равен 1.

**bitIndex**  - позиция бита, значения которого вы хотите проверить.

**Пример:**

исходный байт (a) - 1 1 0 0 **1** 1 0 0

инверсия данного байта (~a) - 0 0 1 1 **0** 0 1 1

(~a ^ (1 << 5 - 1)) - 0 0 1 1 **1** 0 1 1

a & (~a ^ (1 << 5 - 1)) - 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

**Пример 2:**

исходный байт (a) - 1 1 0 0 **0** 1 0 0

инверсия данного байта (~a) - 0 0 1 1 **1** 0 1 1

(~a ^ (1 << 5 - 1)) - 0 0 1 1 **0** 0 1 1

a & (~a ^ (1 << 5 - 1)) - 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Answer (score 1):

Если нужны ведущие нули

```
byte[] data = {127,126,125};

    for (byte datum : data) {
        String bitsString = Integer.toBinaryString(datum & 0xff | 0x100).substring(1);
        System.out.println(bitsString); //Напечатайте, или сделайте с битами что-то ещё
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !